# serving content of unbounded size in http in golang

Tags: http, go

I have the following server code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type serveData struct {

}

func (s *serveData) Read (p []byte)  (int, error) {
    l := len (p)
    fmt.Println ("p size is ", l);
    time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond);
    return l, nil;
}

func (s *serveData) Seek (offset int64, whence int)  (int64, error) {
    fmt.Println ("in seek ", offset);
    return offset, nil;
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    reader := new (serveData)
    //w.WriteHeader(206);
    w.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    fmt.Println ("got request");
    http.ServeContent(w, r, "cool", time.Date(2009, time.November, 10, 23, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), reader)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/check", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

When i connect the client to the server above (`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/check`), nothing happens and curl just exits. The server calls `Seek()` function 2 times, but never calls `Read()`

I am serving partial content, as the size is unbounded (pseudo-live data). Also, when I uncomment `w.WriteHeader(206)`, the server complains about "`http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls`"

What possibly is going wrong here?

Comment: You need a working seek function.  Also, let ServeContent handle the status code.

Comment: my bad! ignored the "whence" field.